# Twitter API v2 with RestSharp

Tags: c#, vb.net, twitter, restsharp, http-status-code-401

I've been trying to understand the new Twitter API for a while now.
For this I have helped myself to the `RestSharp` library.
In itself I would also like this code to work in vb.net
I have the basic plan.

```
var authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForAccessToken(
                CONSUMER_KEY,
                CONSUMER_TOKEN,
                ACCESS_TOKEN,
                ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
                AuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1
            );
            
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://api.twitter.com/2")
{
    Authenticator = authenticator
};

var client = new RestClient(options);

var request = new RestRequest("/tweets");
request.Method = RestSharp.Method.Post;
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("status", "test", ParameterType.GetOrPost);

Console.WriteLine(request);
var response = client.Execute(request);
var json_response = response.Content;
Console.WriteLine(json_response);
```

Unfortunately, the authentication does not work.
I get the following error:

```
{
  "title": "Unauthorized",
  "type": "about:blank",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Unauthorized"
}
```

The tokens are not the problem, as it works in Python and in Postman

Comment: _the authentication does not work_.  What exactly dose does not work mean.  Are you getting exceptions, are you getting something other than a 200 response?!or some other behaviour?

Comment: I get the Unauthorized 401 error

Comment: You are using a very old auth endpoint. Check this, it works https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/d0b4b1842859ff3c61c7a6151ba273f3a8577f95/test/RestSharp.InteractiveTests/TwitterClient.cs